# Jsp controller file confusion

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm not entirely sure what a .jsp controller file is? 
In this file is java the only language allowed?

What languages can be written within jsp code/files? Only Java HTML and XML right?

Comment: Jsp is usually a "view", not "controller". Usually controller is just a regular java class.

Comment: HTML, JavaScript, CSS, Java (through scriplets, but you don't really want it) and use taglibs.

Comment: Controller => Servlet

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confused between different terms. I think this article called [Scriptless JSP Pages: The Front Man](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/frontman.html) can both help you understand the difference between model, view, controller, etc. and how they are usually implemented in a JSP context.

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about "controller", they're usually referring to the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) concept which is basically an architectural concept that says your application will be better structured if it separates what's the presentation, what is the logic and what's just data.

So the idea here is that if you have these 3 layers well defined, switching the persistence backend, or switching the frontend UI, or even reusing the logic and the backend in a new UI (for example, creating a mobile native version for your web app) is an easier task.

Now, about using JSP as a controller. A JSP is a template that is compiled into a java class called Servlet. The Servlet idea is simple and it's basically a way to treat requests and produce responses in a scalable way. So the idea of using the JSP as a controller is not a completely crazy idea :-). If you think that web pages can forward http requests to a servlet, why couldn't they forward their requests to a JSP? Actually they can.

But historically, JSP has been used mainly in the presentation layer (the V of the MVC), so, usually, when people talk about "Controllers" in a java web app, they're usually referring to explicit Servlets (I mean, those ones not generated by JSPs) and Managed Beans (for JSF). Because JSPs are commonly used to generate HTML, it's commonly agreed that JSP are UI, not controllers.